# Create an instance of Vertex AI Platform Notebooks Error

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I was trying to create an instance of Vertex AI Platform Notebooks. I did the following steps:

1. Created a folder in my home directory.

```
cd
mkdir tmp-workspace
cd tmp-workspace
```

2. Created a requirements file with the Python packages to install in the custom image.

```
gsutil cp gs://cloud-training/OCBL203/requirements.txt .
```

3. Created a Dockerfile that defines your custom container image:

```
gsutil cp gs://cloud-training/OCBL203/Dockerfile .
```

4. Build the image and push it to your project's Container Registry:

```
IMAGE_NAME=kfp-dev
TAG=latest
IMAGE_URI="gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/${IMAGE_NAME}:${TAG}"
gcloud builds submit --timeout 15m --tag ${IMAGE_URI} .
```

5. I got an error message in the last step:

   ```
   "BUILD FAILURE: Build step failure: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 125
    ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) build bfddda01-a24d-4c2e-9627-2a4b1286f5d1 completed with status "FAILURE""

    starting build "bfddda01-a24d-4c2e-9627-2a4b1286f5d1"

    FETCHSOURCE
    Fetching storage object: gs://qwiklabs-gcp-03-6c5d81f51663_cloudbuild/source/1682468208.61265-0037520e88db4ff782dfe7c08e1dc5e9.tgz#1682468209180714
    Copying gs://qwiklabs-gcp-03-6c5d81f51663_cloudbuild/source/1682468208.61265-0037520e88db4ff782dfe7c08e1dc5e9.tgz#1682468209180714...
    / [1 files][  393.0 B/  393.0 B]
    Operation completed over 1 objects/393.0 B.
    BUILD
    Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    invalid argument "gcr.io//kfp-dev:latest" for "-t, --tag" flag: 
    invalid reference format
    See 'docker build --help'.
    ERROR
    ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 125
   ```

---

```
BUILD FAILURE: Build step failure: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 125
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) build bfddda01-a24d-4c2e-9627-2a4b1286f5d1 completed with status "FAILURE"

"BUILD FAILURE: Build step failure: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 125
```

Comment: Why does it reference a qwiklabs (now Cloud Skillsboost) GCS bucket?   Is this from an actual qwiklabs lab that you're seeing this error or are you trying to reference a bucket that you saw in a lab?  Because those bucket names are usually named after the randomly generated project IDs, which are ephemeral.

Comment: It is part of creating a pipeline instance on vertex AI on GCP. I've already created the cluster on Kubernetes Engine and Cloud Storage. It's part of Google job.